# How can I resolve this exception when I associate a Role with a User?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data

I have been new in programming for a few months and I am developing my first official project. I am having this problem when I try to create a User by assigning a role.
I have a User class which has a Set  roles = new HashSet <> ().
Then I have a Role class which has a String nameRole which is the same id for the table.
I inserted the roles directly into the DB with insert. When I add the User I have this exception:

Thank you in advance and I apologize if it will be trivial for you but I am new to programming.

**javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find com.work.portal.model.Role with id string**

User class

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "user")
@ApiModel(description = "Details about the user")
public class User implements Serializable, UserDetails {

   @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private String lastname;

    @ApiModelProperty(notes = "The user's email/username")
    @Column(name = "email", unique = true)
    private String username;

    private String password;

    @Type(type = "yes_no")
    private Boolean requestChangePassword = Boolean.FALSE;

    private Date dateCreated;

    private Date dateLastLogin;

    @Type(type = "yes_no")
    private Boolean enabled= Boolean.TRUE;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)"),
                inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(16)"))
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();


    public void addRole(Role role) {
        this.roles.add(role);
```

Role class

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "role")
@ApiModel(description = "Details about the role")
public class Role implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(16)")
    private String name;

}
```

UserService method addUser

```
@Autowired
private RoleRepository roleRepository;

public User addUser(User user) {                                         
    if (!user.getUsername().equals("admin")) {                           
        user.addRole(roleRepository.findById("ROLE_ADMIN").get());       
    } else {                                                             
        user.addRole(roleRepository.findById("ROLE_PARTNER").get());     
    }                                                                    
    return userRepository.save(user);                                    
}
```

Role Repository

```
@Repository("roleRepository")
public interface RoleRepository extends JpaRepository<Role, String> {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

even though it's hard for me to understand why you need a whole role table instead of just putting an enum attribute
i'll suggest maybe try to put

> private Set  roles ;
> instead of
> private Set  roles = new HashSet<>();

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried to follow your advice by only putting private Set <Role <> roles but I get the same exception

Comment: is it possible that it does not recognize the field role_id   in the join
                inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id", ..     i see no attribute called role_id in the class Role  try to change it by name